# This program is showing sisegv on codechef. Segmentation fault it is. But i cant find any suitable way to remove it

Tags: arrays, segmentation-fault

This is the problem statement: [codechef problem](https://www.codechef.com/AOTI2017/problems/AOTI17D)
And my code is:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    char p[100];
    char n[100][100];
    int main()
    {
        int a,c=0;
        int x,y,z=0;
        scanf("%d",&a);
        while(a--)
        {
            int mid,l,i,j,f;
            scanf("%s",p);
            l=strlen(p);
            mid=l/2;
            if(l%2==0)
            {
                f=0;
                for(i=0,j=l-1;i<=mid,j>mid;i++,j--)
                {
                    if(p[i]!=p[j])
                    {
                        f=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(f==0)
                {
                    strcpy(n[c],p);
                    c++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                f=0;
                for(i=0,j=l-1;i<mid,j>mid;i++,j--)
                {
                    if(p[i]!=p[j])
                    {
                        f=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(f==0)
                {
                    strcpy(n[c],p);
                    c++;
                }
            }

        }
        for(x=0;x<=c;x++)
        {
            for(y=x+1;y<=c;y++)
            {
                if(n[x][0]==n[y][0])
                z++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d",z);
    }
```

The output is working fine. But i cant understand why segmentation fault is showing up every time i submit my code. I even tried to reduce my array size and also reduce the 2D array size as well. Nothing is working. It seems like i am accessing array out of bounds but i cant find it. Can anyone suggest alternate way to do it as well?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes. It is working fine on local compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like i am accessing array out of bounds but I can't find it.

Well, you don't do any bounds checks, so it's trivial to construct input for which your code *does* access array out of bounds. For example, this statement:

```
scanf("%s",p);
```

will overflow `p[100]` if the input line is longer than 99 characters.

Likewise, giving your program 101 input strings will overflow the `n[100][100]` array.

Do you *know* what input your program is being tested on when you "submit your code"?

Comment: constraints are:
Number of strings<=10^6
and string>=1

Comment: @SayanDhar "Number of strings<=10^6" -- well, your program doesn't handle more than a 100, so that might be your problem right there,.